# Nullable object must have a value on add migration abp v 3.0.0

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate

I get error 'Nullable object must have a value' when add migration in ef code first, but i can not find position of error in code or maybe bug in abp framework.
how find location of error when execute command in Package Manager Console.
but when i remove all my custom Entities from DbContext and remove mapping files, this error not appear.

Stacktrace:

```
PM> add-migration Init_Db
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Nullable object must have a value.
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.DetachRelationship(ForeignKey foreignKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasBaseType(EntityType baseEntityType, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.DerivedTypeDiscoveryConvention.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.RunVisitor.VisitOnEntityTypeAdded(OnEntityTypeAddedNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAddedNode.Accept(ConventionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionVisitor.Visit(ConventionNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionVisitor.VisitConventionScope(ConventionScope node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionScope.Accept(ConventionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionVisitor.Visit(ConventionNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionVisitor.VisitConventionScope(ConventionScope node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.DiscoverRelationships(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(EntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(TypeIdentity type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.Entity(Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetModel>b__0(Object k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Nullable object must have a value.
```

Comment: Do any of your custom entities have self-referencing relationships? Otherwise, can you remove your custom entities one-by-one to narrow down the cause - and show it?

Comment: When i wrote mapping for entities, i solved mapping errors with your solution but it is very hard and time consuming. But you gave me a good tip "self-referencing relationships".

Comment: I have not checked yet.

Comment: I move entities and mapping files from abp v2 template to abp v3 template,
but in abp v2 i can add migration and update database without any problem but in abp v3 i get error. @aaron

Comment: yes i have one entity has self referencing, i excluded this entity and all related entity from project but i get error
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.BankAccounts' of type 'ICollection<BankAccount>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: i add fluent mapping on overrided OnModelCreating method
...
                modelBuilder.AddConfiguration(new ApplicationUserMap());
                modelBuilder.AddConfiguration(new BankAccountMap());
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

but i think this method never called because i add exception on first line of this method but it not throwed!

Comment: I thought it might be a problem related to self referencing, but i explained, i exclude this entity and all related entity from project.

Comment: Check your SEED method. The problem is propably in seeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 2 days i found error

The reason for the error is the commented code

```
public abstract class EntityMapConfiguration<T> : DbEntityConfiguration<T> where T : class
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> entity)
    {
        //if (typeof(ICreationAudited<ApplicationUser>).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        //{
        //    entity.HasOne(nameof(ICreationAudited<ApplicationUser>.CreatorUser))
        //        .WithOne()
        //        .HasForeignKey(typeof(T), "CreatorUserId");
        //}
        //if (typeof(IModificationAudited<ApplicationUser>).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        //{
        //    entity.HasOne(nameof(IModificationAudited<ApplicationUser>.LastModifierUser))
        //       .WithOne()
        //       .HasForeignKey(typeof(T), "LastModifierUserId");
        //}

        if (typeof(IHasConcurrency).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            entity.Property(nameof(IHasConcurrency.RowVersion)).IsRowVersion();
    }
}
```

and finally solve mapping errors with following code, but i can not understand why mapping worked without any problem in Ef core 1 and in Ef Core 2 has error

```
entity.HasOne(x => x.Bank).WithOne().HasForeignKey<BankAccount>(x => x.BankId);
```